# Show "Save as dialog" before closing Excel file created by EPPlus (way without macro)

Tags: c#, excel, xlsx, epplus

Is there any possibility to create and open XLSX (not macro) file generated by EPPlus with forced show "Save as dialog" before closing Excel?

**My scenario:**
I create XLSX file with EPPlus and store it to temporary folder of my application. Then I immediately call this file to run (Excel will open and my file is loaded). Without any changes I close Excel - and in this moment I want to force dialog "Save as" to save this file into other directory (not my temporary). Can you force display this dialog by any property of file (or other way)?

**Solved for XLSM:**
If someone of you need show this "Save as" dialog for Excel macro file (XLSM) using EPPlus, this is the way:

```
OfficeOpenXml.ExcelPackage Package;
  Package.Workbook.CreateVBAProject();
  OfficeOpenXml.VBA.ExcelVBAModule excelVbaModule =
    Package.Workbook.VbaProject.Modules.AddModule("Module1");
  StringBuilder mac = new StringBuilder();
  mac.AppendLine("Sub Auto_Close()");
  mac.AppendLine("Application.Dialogs(xlDialogSaveAs).Show");
  mac.AppendLine("End Sub" );
  excelVbaModule.Code = mac.ToString();
Package.Save()
```

Can you help me with not macro file? (But maybe it is not possible)
Thanks.

**What I did based on your responses?**
I try using `SaveAs` (instead of the original `.Save()`) from EPPlus:

```
System.IO.FileInfo fileInfo = new System.IO.FileInfo(targetTemporaryFile);
if (fileInfo.Exists) { fileInfo.Delete(); }
Package.SaveAs(fileInfo);
```

But no dialog was displayed.

Comment: for which you want to do it? windows or web application

Comment: it is for windows application

Comment: there is saveas fucntion comes you can use that

Comment: @raman this approach not work for me. I try rewrite it as show above in question. But dialog to save did not appear.

Comment: Have you considered opening that dialog box to prompt for a filename first? Then with that filename, you generate the Excel file with EPPlus. Then you just save directly to the folder that the user wanted.

Comment: @VincentTan yes, I do that this way, but I was asking if there is any possibility to do this from excel.. Yet it seems that it is not possible, but yes, I can use this hint. Thanks for reply.

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to flag the FileInfo object corresponding to the Package as Read Only - `myFile.IsReadOnly = True`

In this way if the user tries to just save the file, they will be given the Save As.. dialog.  I use this on web pages for our intranet by saving the file then handing the user a link to the `FileInfo.FullName` property

Comment: Great idea :) Thanks. But because this work only if I change something in document I cannot accept this as final solution.